# thanks status when mail send with PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I want to display a thanks message when mail is send with PHP

I tried something like

```
if(mail){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bedankt!');</script>";}
```

But I can't get the alert.
I direct my form to mail.php but when the mail.php is done it redirects again to index.html with `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Can this be the reason it doesn't show the alert? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

My code:

```
        <form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="bedanktBericht()">
            <input class="invoeren" name="naamUser" type="text" placeholder="Naam" required>
            <input class="invoeren" name="nummerUser"  type="text" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required>
            <input class="invoeren" name="onderwerpUser"  type="text" placeholder="Onderwerp" required>
            <textarea class="invoeren" type="text" name="opmerkingUser"  placeholder="Opmerking" required></textarea>           
            <button type="submit" id="contactButton" >Verstuur</button>
        </form>

<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ob_start(); 

$naamUser = $_POST['naamUser'];
$nummerUser = $_POST['nummerUser'];
$onderwerpUser = $_POST['onderwerpUser'];
$opmerkingUser = $_POST['opmerkingUser'];


$formcontent="Aanvraag formulier Domein naam \n
Naam: $naamUser \n
Telefoonnummer: $nummerUser \n
Onderwerp: $onderwerpUser \n
Opmerking: $opmerkingUser \n              
              ";              

$recipient = "email@email.nl";

$subject = "Terug Bellen";

$mailheader = "From:  \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");


header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); /* Stuur de browser naar www.site.nl */  

if(mail){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bedankt!');</script>";}
?>
```

**Edit 2:**
I want to execute the alert on the index.html page.
Not mail.php. That's why I tried using the echo after the redirect.

Comment: submit your complete code

Comment: Redirecting won;t make it work.. Though it seems code needs to be analysed before further comment!

Comment: if(mail){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bedankt!');</script>";} is wrong..use the alert condition in the first mail sentence..

Comment: **Note:** `mail()` returns `TRUE` is it have been *accepted for delivery*. It doesn't mean it's actually been delivered.

Comment: Another way is to use 'PHP Flash Messages' which is where you store a massage in $_SESSION and check of the 'destination' page to display the message if set. The message is then deleted.

Comment: @Blank please check my edited code may this help ;)

Comment: @Blank I went to through all of the comments you want to display message on `.html` file & you dint want to change its extension to php, for your kind information you cant run any dynamic script inside html unless you use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this on **mail.php** may it solve:

```
if(mail(paramiters...)){
    header('location:index.html?msg=successfull');
}
```

Now on **index.html**:

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var succ = getParameterByName('msg');
if(succ=='successfull'){
    alert('bedankt!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I cant change my index.html to .php I must keep it at .html is there another way?

Comment: @Sourabh Please check the [How to format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page to format your answers.

Comment: @Blank You must have a .php file otherwhise your php code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are redirecting the user before the alert:

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); // Redirect

// This code is never reached
if(mail){echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bedankt!');</script>";}
```

Furthermore, your `if` statement is written wrong. Something like this would make more sense:

```
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bedankt!');</script>";
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); // Redirect
} else {
    die("Error!");
}
```

However, `echo` is not the correct way to handle this, and I doubt you can make it work this way.

Try looking into [Ajax](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/), I think this is better suited for your issue. You can find some explanation [here](https://gist.github.com/Zirak/3086939) as well.

Comment: `header` wont redirect because there is output before it. (unless you use output buffering)